# Excel: Not sure how to solve error MdxScript(Model) (6,55) Calculation error when refreshing pivot tables

Tags: excel, dax, datamodel

I have an Excel file with multiple pivot tables linked to the same data model. I use the following function to display the fields as text in the pivot tables:

`=CONCATENATEX(Table;[Worker];",")`

The result is a simple pivot table per department with employee names and their status.

When refreshing the pivot table to update the status of the employees I receive the following error: "The query did not run or the Data Model could not be accessed. Here's the error message we got:

> MdxScript(Model) (6,55) Calculation error in measure 'Table'[Worker]: Column 'Worker' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression".

After this happens Excel empties the data model and none of the pivots work anymore. It was working fine last week and I didn't change any settings, nor column header for Worker, although there might have been an O365 update in the meantime.

Hope somebody out there knows how to solve this! Any help appreciated :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause: in the tab PivotTable Tools Analyze > Data > Connection Properties you get a pop up. In the pop-up, under the tab Defintion > Command text for some reason the text had changed from
`'Table'!$A:$H`
to
`'Table'!$A:$A`

Changing it back to $A:$H solved my issue. Still odd that Excel decided to change the definition itself...